# Creating a block matrix from arrays of blocks

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I am trying to generate a matrix from square blocks. Effectively, I have a $n×n$ matrix polynomial $P(l)$, the $qth$ derivative of $P(l)$ with respect to $l$, which is denoted by $P^{(q)} (l)$, and a block of zeroes, which I’ll just call $0$. I have some integer $k$ such that if $k=1$ then I am generating the matrix

$$ R= \begin{pmatrix} P(l) \end{pmatrix} $$

If $k=2$ then I should generate

$$ R = \begin{pmatrix} P(l) & 0 \\ \frac{1}{1!} P^{(1)}(l) & P(l) \end{pmatrix} $$

If $k=3$ then

$$ R = \begin{pmatrix} P(l) & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{1!} P^{(1)}(l) & P(l) & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2!} P^{(2)}(l) & \frac{1}{1!} P^{(1)}(l) & P(l) \end{pmatrix} $$

and so forth. Generally,

$$ R = \begin{pmatrix} P(l) & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{1!} P^{(1)}(l) & P(l) & \cdots & 0 
& 0 \\ \frac{1}{2!} P^{(2)}(l) & \frac{1}{1!} P^{(1)}(l) & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ \frac{1}{(k-1)!} P^{(k-1)}(l) & \frac{1}{(k-2)!} P^{(k-2)}(l) & \cdots & \frac{1}{1!} P^{(1)}(l) & P(l) \end{pmatrix} $$

is an $nk×nk$ matrix.

I prefer a simple and understandable way and for that I thought to start with a zero matrix $R$ of dimensions $nk×nk$ and then with two "for" loops to full the initial zero matrix, putting the corresponding derivative which is needed. I’m not sure in what should go as my statement in "for" loops. I found other questions which were similar but more complicated and specific. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you seen `ArrayFlatten`?

Answer (score 4):

Because of the banded structure of your matrix, you may use the undocumented function `` SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix `` for that as follows (using a dummy matrix-valued function `P` here):

```
P[i_, l_, n_] := ConstantArray[l, {n, n}];
R[k_, l_, n_] := SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[
  Table[Band[{i, 1}] -> 1/i! P[i, l, n], {i, 1, k}], 
  {k, k}
  ]
```

E.g., `R[4, ell, 3]` produces a matrix of size `{12, 12}` with block entries specified by the function `P`.

Comment: Oh thanks, i didn't know about `Band` and how to use `SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix`.

Answer (score 2):

First we need same data. I denote your "P(l)" bl p[l] and `P^(1)" by der[n,p,x]. Then I define a function "makeblmat" that assembles the block matrix:

```
m = Table[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}], 2, 2];
p[x_] = Sum[MatrixPower[m, i] x^i, {i, 0, 2}];
derp[n_, p_, x_] := D[p, {x, n}];
makeblmat[k_] := 
 Table[If[i >= j, derp[i - j, p[x], x]/! (i - j), 0], {i, k}, {j, k}]//ArrayFlatten;
MatrixForm[makeblmat[2]]
```

[image]

Comment: `MatrixForm` does not define matrices. Like virtually all built-in symbols ending on `Form`, it is just a wrapper for display purposes. Better use `ArrayFlatten`.

Comment: Who said MatrixForm would make a matrix? It is only forto display the  output. The matrix is created by "makeblmat" meaning: make block matrix.

Comment: I pointed out the purpose of `MatrixForm` because this symbol is frequently an issue on this site. Moreover, `makeblmat[k]` creates a $k \times k$ matrix of $n\times n$ matrices, but OP asked for a $(nk) \times (nk)$ matrix as result. And `MatrixForm` does not convert into a $(nk) \times (nk)$ matrix.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher   I gave the matrix in block form. It  is easy to flatten it with ArrayFlatten.

Comment: That's what I am saying.

Comment: @DanielHuber thank you very much. This is also works !